# Mockito - Creating nested mock objects

Tags: java, mockito

I'm learning Mockito. I am facing problem while creating mock for nested objects. See

```
public interface BaseManager {
    public Query createQuery(String queryString);
}
```

and an implementation class for that

```
public class BaseManagerImpl implements BaseManager {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    // ...
}
```

Module level hibernate manager, for example:

```
public interface RegistrationManager {
    @Transactional
    public List<Country> getCountries();
}
```

and an implementation class for that

```
public class RegistrationManagerImpl implements RegistrationManager {
    @Autowired
    private BaseManager baseManager;
    // ...
}
```

Now I'm facing problem in creating mocked base manager. My test class is:

```
 public class MockitoTest {
    private RegistrationManager registrationManager = new RegistrationManagerImpl();

    @Mock private BaseManager baseManager;

    @Mock private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //  baseManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        registrationManager.setBaseManager(baseManager);
    }
    // ...
    // @Test
}
```

Problem: **sessionFactory is not instantiated inside baseManager.**
Please help creating mock object. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, "NullPointerException inside baseManager?" You have mocked your `baseManager` object -- it shouldn't be executing any code that you have not stubbed. There is more you are not showing in this example; please post the actual JUnit test and the *full* stacktrace.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are creating a mock of `BaseManager` but only `BaseManagerImpl` has a  `SessionFactory` field. Mockito doesn't know about `BaseManagerImpl`. In your code you create two mocks which are completely independent of each other.

Unit tests are about testing an **unit**. So you should test `BaseManagerImpl` and `RegistrationManagerImpl` separately.

So you test `BaseManagerImpl` first:

```
public class BaseManagerImplTest {

    private BaseManagerImpl target;

    // ...
}
```

then you test `RegistrationManagerImpl`:

```
public class RegistrationManagerImplTest {

    private RegistrationManagerImpl target;

    // ...
}
```

I suggest that you should use the name `target` or something similar for your test target in your test class becaues it will make your code much more easier to read.

Another thing: If you test an object all of its dependencies should be mocked but you shouldn't care about the mocks' dependencies. You just mock their method invocations like:

```
Mockito.when(myMock.someMethod()).thenReturn(someResultObject);
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. We should not worry about mock's dependencies.

But I have a problem like, 

I have service ServiceA.methodA() which is calling ServiceB.methodB(..), from methodB(...) it is calling ManagerC.serviceC(...). 

In this case, I want to mock only ManagerC.serviceC(...) and want a real call for ServiceB.methodB(..) because I do not want to mock my business layer.

In this case, I have a same problem as one who asked this question.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand this. What do you mean by `real call`?

Comment: I mean FROM service (A.a1), i am making a call to some another service of the same class (A.a2) which in turn make a call to some other class's method (B.b1) and I want to mock only this (B.b1). How its possible ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the `@InjectMocks` annotation before class you want to test and mock the methods which are called by the basemanger or sessionFactory.

```
public class MockitoTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private RegistrationManager registrationManager = new RegistrationManagerImpl();

    @Mock private BaseManager baseManager;

    @Mock private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //  baseManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        registrationManager.setBaseManager(baseManager);

        Mockito.when(baseManager.yourMethod()).thenReturn(someObject);
    }
    // ...
    // @Test
}
```

Hope this is it you're looking for!

Comment: That's not the problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inject a `mock` of `SessionFactory` into a `mock` of `BaseManager`.

As you are testing `RegistrationManagerImpl`, you just need to have a `mock` of `BaseManager`. You can use method stubbing so that the methods `BaseManager` will return the stubbed values when those methods are called from `RegistrationManagerImpl` methods. So, if you have a `RegistrationManagerImpl` as this:

```
public class RegistrationManagerImpl implements RegistrationManager {
    @Autowired
    private BaseManager baseManager;
    // ...
    public String doSomething(){
         return baseManager.process();  
    }
}
```

you can write your `MockitoTest` as this:

```
public class MockitoTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private RegistrationManager registrationManager = new RegistrationManagerImpl();

    @Mock private BaseManager baseManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }
    // ...
    @Test
    public void test() {
    when(baseManager.process()).thenReturn("hello");

    assertEquals("hello", registrationManager.doSomething());
    }
}
```

And while testing `BaseManager`, there you need to use `mock` of `SeesionFactory`.