# How to mock nested objects using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I've read related SO threads, it seems that they are not applying to my specific case.

[Mockito - Creating nested mock objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812651/mockito-creating-nested-mock-objects)

[mock nested method calls using mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732361/mock-nested-method-calls-using-mockito)

We need to write some unit test cases for production code which looks like:

[image]

The case is:

```kotlin
val dbService = LevelDbKVServiceImpl()
...
dbService.insertOrUpdateAssignedField(instance, false)
```

And got the error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property processType has not been initialized
```

The chain is:

#### LevelDbKVServiceImpl.kt

```kotlin
class LevelDbKVServiceImpl {
    fun insertOrUpdateAssignedField(entity: DynamicEntity, needLogin: Boolean): Boolean {
            return LevelDbHelper.insertOrUpdateAssignedField(entity, needLogin)
    }
}
```

#### LevelDbHelper.kt

```kotlin
object LevelDbHelper {
    fun insertOrUpdateAssignedField(entity: DynamicEntity, needLogin: Boolean): Boolean {
        val levelDb = LevelDBHolder.of(needLogin)
        ....
    }
}
```

#### LevelDBHolder.kt

```kotlin
object LevelDBHolder {
    fun of(needLogin: Boolean): LevelDB {
        if(ProcessInstance.isMainProcess()){
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

#### ProcessInstance.kt

```kotlin
object ProcessInstance {
    private lateinit var processType: ProcessType

    // Will init it before other components
    fun init(context: Context) {
        processType = fetchProcessInfo(context)
    }

    fun isMainProcess(): Boolean {
        return processType.alias == PROCESS_MAIN_NAME
    }
}
```

It make sense that `lateinit property processType` should be initialized before test, we may need to refractor the code base to make the objects inject into other object via constructor parameters.

I was wondering is any way to use Mockito to test the `insertOrUpdateAssignedField` without refactoring the code base?